# Use int-templated function with non-constexpr values

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have some function

```
template<int N>
auto foo();
```

I want to call this function with template parameters that are unknown at compile time, but they can only be numbers 1 to `c` (where `c` is a fixed constant, e.g. 10). Is there a better general solution to this problem than the following?

```
auto foo(int n)
{
  switch(n) {
    case 1:
      return foo<1>();
    case 2:
      return foo<2>();
...
    case 10:
      return foo<10>();
  }
}
```

This solution is getting quite verbose if the function shall be used for a larger set of integers.

This template parameter is necessary because the function uses a class with such a template argument where this is used for the size of a static-sized array. But this should not be really relevant for the problem. I cannot change the templated version.

Comment: Not sure how you're going to return anything in a function declared as `void`. Is this just a dispatcher? If so, what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Template parameters must be known at compile time, there isn't much you can do really. The obvious question is, do you really need that `N` to be a template parameter?

Comment: You can at least use a macro like `#define CASE(num) case num : return foo<num>()` and then you'd have `switch(n) CASE(1); CASE(2); ...; CASE(N);`

Comment: Do you mean [constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)?

Comment: Sure, a `return;` makes sense, but a `return fn()` doesn't really. I have no idea what useful work this code could actually do given its current form. This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) so can you explain why you're even going down this path?

Comment: @tadman you can return an expression with type `void` from a `void` function, including a call to another `void` function.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, obviously, but it looks ridiculous.

Comment: @tadman That's a matter of taste, I guess. I like the consistency with value-returning functions when expressing "now we fully delegate to that other function".

Comment: @Quentin Perhaps something that functional programmers prefer? Can see how that makes sense from that perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure:

```cpp
template <int... Ns>
decltype(auto) dispatch_foo(int const n, std::integer_sequence<int, Ns...>) {
    static constexpr void (*_foos[])() { &foo<Ns>... };
    return _foos[n]();
}

template <int Nmax>
decltype(auto) dispatch_foo(int const n) {
    return dispatch_foo(n, std::make_integer_sequence<int, Nmax>{});
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
dispatch_foo<c>(n);
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/88vkvNvfVazMr8Tb)

Comment: Can you get this working for `foo` to be a template parameter? I'm too dumb to figure it out myself.

Comment: @Timo not quite... function templates (and function overload sets) are pretty unwieldy to pass around, and clang just died on me when I tried something with nested variadic lambdas :p

Comment: @Timo [there we go](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cyjc0Oduh2Mmb88W). A bit clunky and it still crashes Clang, but GCC is fine with it.

Comment: Nice, although you have to use a wrapper here. I've got something similar working, but I couldn't do it with a function template directly.

Comment: @Timo to my knowledge that's not possible. Function templates (and overload sets) are just not "things" in C++, so you can't express them as a parameter anywhere. I believe there is a standard proposal somewhere to do something about that.

Comment: @Quentin even where it's done in library for things like invoke, involves wrappers, SFINAE variations, if constexpr constructs, etc, because place of function mabe  takes by a callable, e.g a functor, etc. Another level of craziness if we consider non-static member functions as possible handlers. It's something very costly to develop. No wonder that libraries like Qt go with cheap route of meta-object compiling instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you can call an addition helper function, what about using a sequence of integers (from `std::make_integer_sequence<MAX>{}`) where `MAX-1` is max value for your integer value) combined with template folding, ternary operator and comma operator?

I mean... what about as follows?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <int N>
void foo ()
 { std::cout << N << '\n'; }

template <int ... Is>
void foo (int n, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
 { ((n == Is ? (foo<Is>(), 0) : 0), ...); }

void foo (int n)
 { foo(n, std::make_integer_sequence<int, 42>{}); }

int main()
 {
   foo(2); // print 2
   foo(3); // print 3
   foo(5); // print 5
   foo(7); // print 7
 }
```

If you can use C++20 (so template lambdas) you can avoid the additional (external) function and your `foo()` can be simply written

```
void foo (int n)
 { 
   [&]<int ... Is>(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
        { ((n == Is ? (foo<Is>(), 0) : 0), ...); }
    (std::make_integer_sequence<int, 42>{});
 }
```